# Why does Spring Boot refresh the context right after preparing the context

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am reading the source code of Spring Boot and I found that Spring Boot refreshes the context right after preparing the context in the run method.

SpringApplication.run method:

```
...
prepareContext(context, environment, listeners, applicationArguments,printedBanner);
refreshContext(context);
...
```

Can anyone explain why refreshing context is needed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because `refreshContext` causes context initialization/reinitialization, such as invoking `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` beans, registering listeners, initilizing message source etc. You can see it in sources of the `AbstractApplicationContext#refresh` method.

Here you can find [an article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1195578/Spring-Context-Internals-Part-Refresh) about Spring internals and refresh process.